# Asp.net MVC 4, How making Master Detail in the same form

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-4

I use entity Framework 4.2 and MVC 4

I Got this model/Database structure

**UserInformation**
UserID(PK) 
FirstName 
LastName 
Email

**UserFavoriteColor** 
FavID(PK) 
Color 
Why 
UserID(FK)

Is it possible in one Create Controller Action to fill the UserInformation table and then Fill the UserFavoriteColor.

I Know I could perform this in two steps by creating 2 separates sectiosn. But this is not what I want.

[image]

Comment: Is this really MVC4 like your title says? or mvc-3 like your tag says?

Comment: Updated didn't know the mvc 4 tag was there

Comment: Are you trying to do this via ajax? or standard postback?

Comment: I would like to use a standard postback. The Entity UserInformation contain a collection of UserFavoriteColor . When I call my Create Method in the controller, I Receive a UserInformation object and can Save the Userinformation correctly in the database. Where it's more complicated, is to get the FavoriteColor collection and Save It. I Think the ID and Name attribute for the Color Textbox and the Why Textbox should use a naming convention, but I don't know it.

Comment: Yes, what you require is common. Have you tried using the ViewModel pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, you would use jQuery to insert a new row.  Since we don't know what your code looks like, it's hard to show you exactly how this should be done, but you can look at the examples here:

http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

The trick is that you have to name them appropriately so that the model binder will add them to your collection when you click save.  Then you have to write code in your post method to walk through the list of colors and add any records that don't exist already.

This is a relatively complex thing, so it's not something that can be easily covered in a single answer here.

Another option is to simply have an action for the add-new button, and this inserts a blank record into the data collection, which on postback will now get 3 records (one of them with null values).  When you fill in the values, it will then postback to the main post method and udate the blank record.

This solution has the drawback that if the user adds a new record and doesn't save, the blank record stays in the database.

Comment: I try that, and thats works great. Just one thing. In this example that use a poco class. Is there a way to use that principe with database first. When I do Update Model From Database + T4 dbcontext, that generate me 2 classes.UserInformation.cs and UserFavoriteColor.cs. In UserInformation.cs I have ICollection<UserFavoriteColor> UserFavoriteColors {get;set;}. As you can see, it's an ICollection, not a List like the link you give me.

Comment: @Jean-Francois - an ICollection is similar to a List, you should be able to adapt it.  You can add and remove items, just like a list.

Comment: In the example he use for (int i=0; i < Model.FavouriteMovies.Count; i++) { Html.TextboxFor(model => model.FavouriteMovies[i].Title) } Here we see that he use [i] to move in the List of FavouriteMovies. In my case, I try to do the same thing and I cannot use [i] like him. The only way I can loop throught my ICollection<UserFavoriteColor> is like that for (int i=0; i < Model.MyUserInfo.UserFavoriteColors.Count; i++) { @Html.TextboxFor(model => Model.MyUserInfo.UserFavoriteColors.elementAt(i).Color ) }. The html result doesn't give me the proper ID composition with elementAt.

Comment: @Jean-Francois - You can convert an ICollection to a List.  Model.MyUserInfo.UserFavoriteColors.ToList()

Comment: If I Convert .ToList, here is the result Html.TextboxFor(model => Model.MyUserInfo.UserFavoriteColors.ToList()[i].Color ) } .The name HTML attribute of the textbox generatted is [0].Color. This is not correct. In your link that you give me in the answer, the name attribute generated should be  MyUserInfo.UserFavoriteColor[0].Color ? Thanks a lot for your help Myster Man

Comment: I finaly follow correcly the link you told me in your example and it's work :) . I'm very very happy. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Your first link is broken.