# How to receive the form post and validate using ViewModels in one form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model A has two property and model B strongly-typed with a model class of IEnumerable

**Expect to achieve the following:**
Receive the form data -> validate the two model -> transfer the collection.

**Technical Difficulty:**

```
Form data: 
Model A: 
property one, property two data [Pass] 

Model B:  
Rec#1: Title, Firstname, Lastname [Available in the collection] 
Rec#2: Title, Firstname, lastname [Not available in the collection]
```

I submit two row of data using model B to the controller (see the pic). Collection only contains first row of data.
Model b that is strongly typed class unable to validate the collection or don’t know how to collect the data and validate. How to do this?

Model A

```
public class TestOneModel
{
    [Required]
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Model B

```
public class PassengerModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter first name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First Name not be exceed 20 char")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter last name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "LastName not be exceed 20 char")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public TestOneModel TestOne { get; set; }
    public PassengerModel NewPassenger { get; set; }
    public List<PassengerModel> Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MultipleModelsDemo.ViewModels.IndexViewModel
@using MultipleModelsDemo.ViewModels.vmConstants
@using MultipleModelsDemo.Helpers
@{
    Html.Raw(TempData["passengerOrdering"]);
}
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyEditActionOne", "Checkout"))
    {       
        <div>
            <h4>Send Model One</h4>
            <fieldset>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "ValidationSummary")
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestOne.PropertyOne)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestOne.PropertyOne)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TestOne.PropertyOne)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestOne.PropertyTwo)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestOne.PropertyTwo)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TestOne.PropertyTwo)
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
            <div style="margin:3%;">
                @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Checkout/Index.cshtml", Model.Passengers)*@

                @foreach (var item in Model.Passengers)
                {
                    //Html.RenderPartial("EditorRow", item);
                    <div class="editorRow">
                        //@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PassengerModel")) 
                        //{
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["passengerOrdering"])  
                            <li>
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassenger.Title, "Title")
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewPassenger.Title, vmConstants.EnqTypes)
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassenger.FirstName, "First Name")
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewPassenger.FirstName, new { size = "25" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassenger.FirstName)
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassenger.LastName, "Last Name")
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewPassenger.LastName, new { size = "25" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassenger.LastName)
                            </li>
                          //}
                     </div>                
                }
            </div>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyEditActionOne(IndexViewModel model)
{           

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Index", model);
    }

    model.Passengers = _repository.GetPassengers();
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

Comment: Incase if anybody looking for the solution, pls visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152977/asp-net-mvc-4-how-making-master-detail-in-the-same-form

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you include that scripts:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
```

And add in:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <appSettings>
```

For validate you can grab errors like this:

```
 ModelState.AddModelError("keyName","Message");
```

And show it:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessage("keyName")
```

Comment: using angular js and so wouldn't be able to use j query at the same time.

Comment: Incase if anybody looking for the solution, pls visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152977/asp-net-mvc-4-how-making-master-detail-in-the-same-form